# DFS on a nested collection in Java

Tags: java, collections, depth-first-search

I have a map like below

```
com1 -> [user1, 100, [com2,com3]]
com2 -> [user3, 100, []]
com3 -> [user2, 100, [com4]]
com4 -> [user1, 100, [com5]]
com5 -> [user2, 100, []]
```

Here each entry refers to a comment and the index 2 of each list is a list of child comments of that map entry. How do I delete all the comments that are related to com1 both directly and indirectly?

Comment: you mentioned BFS. Yes, you can do with BFS. What's the problem you are facing in it's implementation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is example of deleting such comments using DFS

```
public deleteEntry(String entry) {
    if (map.containsKey(entry)) {
        Comment comment = map.get(entry);
        map.remove(entry);
        if (comment.getChildren() != null) {
            for(int i = 0; i < comment.getChildren().size(); i++) {
                deleteEntry(comment.getChildren().get(i));
            }
        }
    }
}
```